# Update links - 'continue' message

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that allows the user to select a file to import data. I have already enabled the `UpdateLinks` message, but I'm still getting a message saying not all links were able to update and if I wish to `continue or edit links`. Is there a way to automatically select `continue`?

```
POS = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Selecteer het bestand POS.xls", FileFilter:="Excel Files *.xls* (*.xls*),")

Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(POS, xlUpdateLinksAlways)
```

Comment: **Post your current code.**

Comment: @Gary'sStudent, added my code to select the files

Comment: `GetOpenFilename` doesn't open any files. Your `Workbooks.Open` command allows you to specify an `UpdateLinks` parameter.

Comment: @rory, right! forgot that part of the code

Comment: In line with @Rory 's comment, see this link for `Workbook.Open` arguments: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194819.aspx